# SQLite Exception raised with message: no such table

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-xe2

I created an application that collects information from the computer (computer name, CPU, Memory, etc) but I am having such a hard time displaying the information stored in the SQLite database, when I execute a query  I get the “NO SUCH TABLE” message when I know for sure I have a table called “hardware”  what am I doing wrong?

Here the code I use to execute the query:

```
procedure TMain.executeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  results: TDataSet;
  query: String;

begin
  outputMemo.ClearSelection;
  query := 'SELECT * FROM hardware;';
  try
    SQLConnection1.Execute(query, nil, results);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      outputMemo.Text := 'Exception raised with message: ' + E.Message;
  end;
  ShowSelectResults(results);
end;
```

The database file and table are created programmatically created every time the application runs

```
procedure CheckForDatabase;
var
  sldb: TSQLiteDatabase;
  sSQL: string;

begin
  slDBPath := ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)) + 'ComputerName.db';
  // ShowMessage(slDBPath);
  sldb := TSQLiteDatabase.Create(slDBPath);
  try
    if sldb.TableExists('hardware') then
      begin
        sSQL := 'DROP TABLE hardware';
        sldb.ExecSQL(sSQL);
      end;

    sSQL := 'CREATE TABLE hardware (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, compname TEXT, username TEXT, model TEXT, manufacturer TEXT, domain TEXT, ip TEXT, serialnumber TEXT)';
    sldb.ExecSQL(sSQL);
    sldb.ExecSQL('CREATE INDEX sHardware ON hardware(CompName);');
    sldb.BeginTransaction;
    sSQL := 'INSERT INTO hardware(id, compname, username, model, manufacturer, domain, ip, serialnumber) VALUES (1, "AMD8537", "OMonge", "Gigabyte", "Gigabyte", "Workgroup", "192.168.1.11", "8746652");';
    sldb.ExecSQL(sSQL);
    sldb.Commit;
  finally
    sldb.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And this is the SQLite database:

[image]

Any help you can provide me with will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What is `SQLConnection1` and how is configured against that database. Do you have correct path to the database file specified there ?

Comment: SQLConnection1 is a TSQL Connection object and yes I do have the absolute path specified, connecting to the database is not the issue.

Comment: Perform "select * from sqlite_master" query and see which tables are really in your DB.

Comment: What is the path of the database file? What is the path in the TSQLConnection object?

Comment: slDBPath := ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)) + 'ComputerName.db';
  
sldb := TSQLiteDatabase.Create(slDBPath);

Comment: And what is the relationship between `sldb` and `SQLConnection1`? Continue connecting the dots until you've shown the full picture. And if you're so sure the connection is not the issue, then what *other* queries can you run that really make you think it's just *this* query that's the problem? Get more evidence before diagnosing the problem.

Comment: The third parameter to `Execute` is wrong. You need to pass a *pointer* to your variable: `@Results`.

Comment: @ Rod Kennedy.  I created the application based on the following sample: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Tutorial:_Connecting_to_a_SQLite_Database_(Delphi)

Comment: Nonetheless, the code is wrong.

Comment: Are you shure you are on XE2 . If so my XE2 TSQLConnection, has no Driver property `Sqlite`.

Comment: @moskito-x that's because I'm using a SQLite wrapper to create the database.

Comment: Wich SQLite wrapper do you use . And this SQLite wrapper has is own `TSQLConnection` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Taged Delphi-XE2 so my answer belongs to XE2

From version RAD Studio XE3 TSQLMonitor supports SQLite databases. ...

With XE2 You can not use `SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;` with Driver `Sqlite` !
Will not work `SQLConnection1.Execute(query, nil, results);`

According to the code used , it seems to be the `simple Delphi wrapper for Sqlite 3` to act.

So you can use the just created `sldb` .

```
slDBPath := ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)) + 'ComputerName.db';
sldb := TSQLiteDatabase.Create(slDBPath);
```

In the `procedure CheckForDatabase;`

remove

```
var
  sldb: TSQLiteDatabase;
```

and put it to the interface of your Application

```
private
    { Private declarations }
    sltb: TSQLIteTable;
    sldb: TSQLiteDatabase;
```

also remove `sldb.Free;` form the finally block

```
finally
    sldb.Free;
end;
```

In your `executeButtonClick(...`

```
procedure TMain.executeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  query: String;

begin
  outputMemo.ClearSelection;
  query := 'SELECT * FROM hardware;';
  sltb := sldb.GetTable(query);
  if sltb.Count > 0 then begin
     //display first row
     ....
  if not sltb.IsLastRow the begin
     sltb.Next;
     //display next row
     ....
```

[how to display field values : look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169484/1322642)