# Exception "No such Table : Table_Name"

Tags: delphi, sqlite

My code raises an exception:

> No such Table : Table_Name

I spent a whole day trying to resolve it but had no success so far.

I used `SQLite3.exe` to create the database, create the table `person` and insert the data. When I query the content of table `person` it shows me the positive result.

Unfortunately, when I use this code to show the table content the exception is raised.

This is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.connectButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Set the path of your database file.
  // Replace "full_path_to_your_database_file" with the absolute path 
  // to your SQLite database file.
  SQLConnection1.Params.Add('Database=D:\testdb.db');
  try
    // Establish the connection.
    SQLConnection1.Connected := true;
    executeButton.Enabled := true;
    outputMemo.Text := 'Connection established!';
  except
    on E: EDatabaseError do
      ShowMessage('Exception raised with message' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.executeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  results: TDataSet;
  query: String;
begin
  outputMemo.Clear;
  // A random query
  query := 'SELECT * FROM person;';

  try
  // Execute the query on the database.
    SQLConnection1.Execute(query, nil, results);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      outputMemo.Text := 'Exception raised with message: ' + E.Message;
  end;
  // Show the results of the query in a TMemo control.
  ShowSelectResults(results);
end;

procedure TForm3.ShowSelectResults(results: TDataSet);
var
  names: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  currentField: TField;
  currentLine: string;
begin
  if not results.IsEmpty then
  begin
    results.First;
    names := TStringList.Create;
    results.GetFieldNames(names);
    while not results.Eof do
    begin
      currentLine := '';
      for i := 0 to names.Count - 1 do
      begin
        currentField := results.FieldByName(names[i]);
        currentLine := currentLine + ' ' + currentField.AsString;
      end;
      outputMemo.Lines.Add(currentLine);
      results.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Exception raised with message: no such table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585953/sqlite-exception-raised-with-message-no-such-table)

Comment: `ShowSelectResults(results);` is member of `TForm1` but you show us `TForm3.ShowSelectResults`  I think `Form1.ShowSelectResults()` has another code wich we can not see !!

Comment: @MartynA :  memory leak : I think you mean `names := TStringList.Create;` instead of `results` !!

Comment: @moskito-x:  Maybe `names` too, but I was talking about the fact that `executeButtonClick` has a local TDataSet object `results` which is created (presumably, but maybe the failure to is what is causing the OP's problem) in some way but not freed.

Comment: @ReneHoffmann : `sldb := TSQLiteDatabase.Create(slDBPath);` what is the library I should add in use clause to use this object `TSQLiteDatabase` ?

Comment: @MartynA : AFAIK `results` TDataSet is set by SQLConnection1.Execute(), you should neither Create or Free it. You're just using it to refer to an existing dataset.

Comment: @moskito-x the problem is the application can't find `person` table  that created in the `testdb.db`, this is the problem !

Comment: @moskito-x:  Well, if it is a TSqlConnection as in DBExpress, you can pass Nil as the third argument to `Execute` **Or** pass an existing dataset, in which case you need to create it first and free it afterwards - `Execute` does **not** create the dataset object

Comment: @moskito-x : This is the exception message :: `Exception raised with message: no such table: person`

Comment: @junior.programmer : have you tried with `Form3.ShowSelectResults(results);` ?

Comment: @junior.programmer : the answer Rene Hoffmann links to is related to [Tim Anderson's SQlite3 wrapper](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/articles/a-simple-delphi-wrapper-for-sqlite-3)

Comment: @MartynA : Look here - [SQLite Databases](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Tutorial:_TSQLMonitor_Support_for_SQLite_Databases). I can not see where `Results` is `created` or `freed` :-)

Comment: @moskito-x:  Aha, my mistake was to look at the code of TSqlConnection in D7, which is rather diiferent from what's in Seattle, f.i.  But I still think that .Execute causes a memory leak:  If in the OP's code, immediately after the call to Execute I set the `Tag` of `results` to 666, then a breakpoint on TDataSet.Destroy shows that Destroy is never actually called on an instance with that `Tag` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your database and/or table is corrupt or there is a mistake in some part of your code which is executing but you are not showing us.

The following code, which creates and populates a new table, runs perfectly on Delphi Seattle and produces the expected result, namely one data row in `outputMemo`.

I suggest you close & restart Delphi and close any other app which might be using the same Sqlite3.Dll as DB does, before trying it.

(I have moved `outputMemo` and `ShowSelectResults` to Form1)

```
procedure TForm1.executeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  results: TDataSet;
  query: String;
begin
  outputMemo.Clear;

  query := 'CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (ID BIGINT, NAME NVARCHAR(80) )';
  SQLConnection1.Execute(query, nil, Nil);

  query := 'INSERT INTO TESTTABLE(ID, NAME) VALUES(1, ''One'')';
  SQLConnection1.Execute(query, nil, Nil);

  query := 'SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE';

  try
  // Execute the query on the database.
    SQLConnection1.Execute(query, nil, results);

  except
    on E: Exception do
      outputMemo.Text := 'Exception raised with message: ' + E.Message;
  end;
  // Show the results of the query in a TMemo control.
  ShowSelectResults(results);

  query := 'DROP TABLE TESTTABLE';
  SQLConnection1.Execute(query, nil, Nil);

end;

procedure TForm1.ShowSelectResults(results: TDataSet);
var
  names: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  currentField: TField;
  currentLine: string;
begin
  if not results.IsEmpty then
  begin
    results.First;
    names := TStringList.Create;
    try
      results.GetFieldNames(names);
      while not results.Eof do
      begin
        currentLine := '';
        for i := 0 to names.Count - 1 do
        begin
          currentField := results.FieldByName(names[i]);
          currentLine := currentLine + ' ' + currentField.AsString;
        end;
        outputMemo.Lines.Add(currentLine);
        results.Next;
      end;
    finally
      names.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What about `names.Free` ?

Comment: @MartynA I'v got this exception when press on execute button `Exception raised with message: External exception C06D007F`

Comment: Using my code?  If so, try rebooting your machine, then moving your existing database to another folder and creating a new one where it was.  If you still get the problem after that, try reinstalling Sqlite.  I don't think your problem has anything to do with Delphi.

Comment: @MartynA also this exception is raised to me `Database table is locked`

Comment: Do what I said in my previous comment.  It sounds like your Sqlite set-up is messed up.