# Lazarus SQLite date entry displays improperly

Tags: sqlite, date, delphi, lazarus

**UPDATE**: Issue was solved by @whosrdaddy. See comments below this question.

I am trying to resolve the following peculiar case: In a friend's Lazarus project, he tries to query an entry in SQLite. The asString()-method (in the procedure for displaying appointments) returns the proper date on Windows 64 Bit. On a 32 Bit operating system, however, only the first two digits are displayed ('16' instead of '28.02.2016'). What could be the reason?

This is the source code for initialising the form:

```
// Initialise Form
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SQLite3Connection1.DatabaseName:='Kalender.sqlite';
  SQLTransaction1.Database:=SQLite3Connection1;
  SQLQuery1.Transaction:=SQLTransaction1;

  // Create Table "tblTermine"
  SQLQuery1.SQL.text := 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblKalender (Datum DATETIME, Termin VARCHAR(10))';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
  SQLTransaction1.commit;
end;
```

There are two further procedures:

```
// Display Appointments
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListBox1.Clear;
SQLQuery1.Close;
SQLQuery1.SQL.text:='SELECT * FROM tblKalender';
SQLQuery1.Open;
while not SQLQuery1.Eof do
  begin
  // Should return 'dd.mm.yyyy'
  ListBox1.Items.add(SQLQuery1.Fields[0].AsString+ ': ' + SQLQuery1.Fields[1].AsString);
  SQLQuery1.Next;
  end;
end;

// Save Appointment
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var Termin: string;
    Datum: TDate;
begin
  Termin:=Edit1.text;
  if calendardialog1.execute then
  Datum:=TDate(calendardialog1.date);
  SQLQUERY1.close;
  SqlQuery1.SQL.text:= 'Insert into tblKalender Values (:Datum, :Termin)';
  SqlQuery1.ParamByName('Datum').AsDate:= Datum;
  SqlQuery1.ParamByName('Termin').AsString:= Termin;
  SqlQuery1.ExecSQL;
  SqlTransaction1.Commit;
  Button1.Click;
  Edit1.Text := '';
end;
```

[The intended output into the TListBox would be something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyC52.png)

Comment: Extract the value as datetime and use FormatDateTime to present the the string in the wanted format...

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how exactly do I extract it as a DateTime-object?

Comment: @Tyrandus : Maybe this answer can help you. [Date and Time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15169484/1322642).

Comment: `SQLQuery1.Fields[0].AsDateTime` should do the trick...

Comment: @moskito-x: Great suggestion.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Thank you!

Comment: @Tyrandus : Did you ever see the two answers ? Leave a comment, mark one of them as helpfull and correct. To leave an question without thanks or whatever is not nice.

Comment: @moskito-x: You're totally right, I just didn't have another look here until now as @ whosrdaddy already provided the solution. I hope, you and the other contributors don't mind.

Comment: @Tyrandus . and you use `AsDatetime` without translation to a `JulianDate` ?

Comment: @moskito-x As far as my friend is concerned, he is fine with the outcome of the function itself. If there are going to be any additional errors, we will surely come back to the conversion algorithm.

Comment: @Tyrandus : Please look at my **Update-2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should convert first the DateTime to a Julian Date

```
function DateTimeToJulianDate(const Datum: TDateTime): Double;
```

and

```
SqlQuery1.SQL.text:= 'Insert into tblKalender Values (:Datum, :Termin)';
SqlQuery1.ParamByName('Datum').AsFloat := DateTimeToJulianDate(Datum);
...
SqlQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

to test and get the value use :
`function TryJulianDateToDateTime(const AValue: Double; ADateTime: TDateTime):Boolean;`

```
if TryJulianDateToDateTime(SQLQuery1.Fields[0].AsFloat,myDate)
   then
   ListBox1.Items.add(DateTimeToStr(myDate)+ ': ' + .....
   else
   ShowMessage('Not a valid Julian date');
```

**Update**

> SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - **REAL as Julian day numbers**, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
>     Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Double Test

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Datum  : TDate;
 myDate : TDateTime;
 JulianDouble : Double;
begin
//  uses ....,DateUtils

Datum := StrToDate('01.01.2013');  //German Culture settings
     Memo1.Lines.Add('01/01/2013 = '+DateTimeToStr(Datum)+ '    TDate as Text');
     Memo1.Lines.Add('01/01/2013 = '+FloatToStr(Datum)   + '           TDate Double');
JulianDouble := DateTimeToJulianDate(Datum);
     Memo1.Lines.Add('01/01/2013 = '+FloatToStr(JulianDouble)  + '    Julian Double');
if TryJulianDateToDateTime(JulianDouble,myDate)
   then
     Memo1.Lines.Add('01/01/2013 = '+DateTimeToStr(myDate)+ '   TDate as Text')
   else
     ShowMessage('Not a valid Julian date');
end;
```

**Output :**

> 01/01/2013 = 01.01.2013   TDate as Text
>   01/01/2013 = 41275         TDate Double
>   01/01/2013 = 2456293,5    Julian Double
>   01/01/2013 = 01.01.2013   TDate as Text

---

**Update-2 :** 
**To write Delphi TDate Double to a SQLite Date field is wrong**

Your comment shows me that you do not know the problems.

Of course you can directly write a Delphi Double value into a database field.  And read it back to a TDateTime.
This will quickly lead to problems.

Examples:

SQLite:

> These functions only work for dates between 0000-01-01 00:00:00 and
>   9999-12-31 23:59:59 (julidan day numbers 1721059.5 through 5373484.5).
>   **For dates outside that range, the results of these functions are
>   undefined.**

- **41275** Delphi TDate Double for 2013/01/01 is outside of above range !!
- SQLite's own date functions can no longer be used.

> **Compute the current date.**
>       SELECT date('now');
>   **Compute the last day of the current month.**
>       SELECT date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');
>   **Compute the date and time given a unix timestamp 1092941466.**
>       SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch');
>   **Compute the date and time given a unix timestamp 1092941466, and compensate for your local timezone**
>       SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
>   **Compute the number of days since the signing of the US Declaration of Independence.**
>       SELECT julianday('now') - julianday('1776-07-04');
>   etc. etc.

- Changing the date value with above functions will give you a double **2456293,5** for a Date **2013/01/01**
  If you now use unproved and pass it to a Delphi TDateTime it will be **3387/11/26**).
  This is not far from the maximum value of a `TDateTimePicker`.
  which is **2958465.5** and means **9999/12/31**

  `DateTimePicker1.DateTime := 2958465.5;`

  DateTimePicker1  **9999/12/31**

**If one already know that it is wrong one should not use it up to a crash.**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Once again thank you for your comprehensive answer. I am going to incorporate the proposals.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses something called [manifest typing](http://sqlite.org/different.html#typing) which means that if you store values of (Delphi) type TDateTime, SQLite will store the underlying floating point value without warning or message, and offer you the value back so you won't notice that SQLite doesn't treat this as a date-time-value, unless you're trying to manipulate the value from SQL.

To counteract this, I use this bit of SQL code to convert Delphi TDateTime values to an actual SQL datetime:

```
datetime('1900-01-01','+'||(myDateField-2)||' day')
```

(see also [here](http://yoy.be/i3065.html))

Comment: Very helpful, as well! Thank you!